# Can't mount my internal harddrive

Tags: windows, mount, hard-drive, edubuntu

Im trying to mount my internal hard drive. Whenever I click on my 320 gb hard disk a pop-up comes up saying "Unable to mount location , cant mount file" Thats all it says and I just got started using edubuntu less then an hour ago so I dont have that much knowledge with this so if the answer could be written in terms a begginer would understand that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the HDD? Check out the [mount command docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount).

Comment: Also, indicate where your op sys is installed, what kind of file system is on the internal hard drive, and paste the results of "cat /proc/partitions" (or the contents of /proc/partitions) into question

Comment: @jwpat7 I have no clue what any of that means. Can you say it so a beginner would understand.

Comment: Yes.  The question does not contain enough information for a solid answer to be given.  Please edit the question and add the requested details to it.  Re kind of file system on the drive, tell how the content on the drive got there.  Re partitions, start a terminal (eg, click roundish Dash icon (at top of launcher or dash icon stack at left edge of screen), type ter into search box, click Terminal), then type `cat /proc/partitions` at the shell prompt in the terminal.  Also tell: Is ubuntu installed on the internal hard drive?  Is it on a live CD? If not, where?

Comment: Note, a [c-c-c webpage](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-get-a-command-line-shell-or-terminal) tells other ways to open a terminal.  Eg try `ctrl-alt-t` with cursor on blank background of screen.  Note, to copy and paste from terminal into question when you edit the question, just highlight the text in the terminal (left press at one end of text, drag cursor to other end of text, left release), move cursor to insertion point, and middle click. If mouse has no middle button or wheel, press left and right buttons at same time to get a “middle click”.